# Apache Mod_Rewrite condition (skip directory) not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have:

-A mod_rewrite rule for a few things, including remove www., force https, and SEO

-A directory called stage that I want these rules to not apply to

Obviously as I'm posting here, the condition isn't being applied or met, and I have no idea why :(

A warning, I manually and automatically (using cPanel) manage my .htaccess, so it's pretty messy and I apologize sincerely in advance. I'd be very grateful if anyone could point out redundancy (I think I may see one but I'm unsure).

I appreciate any help anyone can offer me, even tips and not answers! I'm a beginner (relatively) and a software engineering student, so anything helps :) It may also explain my newbiness.

Here's my .htaccess file for the root public_html directory: 
Thanks in advance :)

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/patters1/public_html

#AddType text/css .css

Options -Indexes
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
  # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/selfcontrol
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/stage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/selfcontrol
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/stage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?a=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pattersoncode\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/pattersoncode\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!.pattersoncode\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/pattersoncode\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^pattersoncode\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/pattersoncode\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pattersoncode.ca/$1 [R=301,L]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript

ErrorDocument 404 /resources/error.php?a=das
ErrorDocument 401 /resources/error.php?a=4sdfdsc
ErrorDocument 403 /resources/error.php?a=4fsd
ErrorDocument 500 /resources/error.php?a=500fdf
ErrorDocument 400 /resources/error.php?a=400dsf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to check your `.htaccess` file with [this tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) by commenting all your lines and uncommenting it one rule at a time. There are many errors / typo / duplicate lines in your code.

Here are a few errors:

Here is a duplicated rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/selfcontrol
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/stage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/selfcontrol
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/stage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1
```

Here you wrote this but I think that you meant `!^pattersoncode\.ca$`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!.pattersoncode\.ca$
```

And you could have combine it with the previous condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pattersoncode\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!.pattersoncode\.ca$
```

Why this rule should only work on port 80 contrary to the previous ones ?

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pattersoncode.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You should remove the `"` characters from this rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/pattersoncode\.ca\/" [R=301,L]
```